# Elasticsearch custom mapping definition

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to upload data to elk in the following format:

```
{
  "location":{
    "timestamp":1522751098000,
    "resources":[
      {
         "resource":{
           "name":"Node1"
          },
          "probability":0.1
      },
      {
        "resource":{
          "name":"Node2"
         },
        "probability":0.01
      }]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to define a mapping this kind of data and I produced he following mapping:

```
{
 "mappings": {
   "doc": {
     "properties": {
        "location": {
           "properties" : {
              "timestamp": {"type": "date"},
              "resources": []
           }
         }
     }
  }
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. how can I define the "resources" array in my mapping?
2. is it possible to define a custom type (e.g. resource) and use this type in my mapping (e.g "resources": `[{type:resource}]`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of things to know about the Elasticsearch mapping. I really highly suggest to read through at least some of [their documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html).

**Short answers first, in case you don't care:**

1. Elasticsearch automatically allows storing one or multiple values of defined objects, there is no need to specify an array. See Marker 1 or refer to their documentation on [array types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html).
2. I don't think there is. Since Elasticsearch 6 only 1 type per index is allowed. Nested objects is probably the closest, but you define them in the same file. Nested objects are stored in a separate index (internally).

---

**Long answer and some thoughts**

Take a look at the following mapping:

```
"mappings": {
    "doc": {
        "properties": {
            "location": {
                "properties": {
                    "timestamp": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "resources": { [1]
                        "type": "nested", [2]
                        "properties": {
                            "resource": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "name": { [3]
                                        "type": "text"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "probability": {
                                "type": "float"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how your mapping could look like. It can be done differently, but I think it makes sense this way - maybe except marker 3. I'll come to these right now:

**Marker 1:** If you define a field, you usually give it a type. I defined `resources` as a `nested` type, but your `timestamp` is of type `date`. Elasticsearch automatically allows storing one or multiple values of these objects. `timestamp` could actually also contain an array of `dates`, there is [no need to specify an array](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html).

**Marker 2:** I defined `resources` as a `nested` type, but it could also be an object like `resource` a little below (where no type is given). Read about nested objects [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html). In the end I don't know what your queries would look like, so not sure if you really need the nested type.

**Marker 3:** I want to address two things here. First, I want to mention again that `resource` is defined as a normal [object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html) with property `name`. You could do that for `resources` as well.

Second thing is more a thought-provoking impulse: Don't take it too seriously if something absolutely doesn't fit your case. Just take it as an opinion.

This mapping structure looks very inspired by a relational database approach. I think you usually want to define document structures for elasticsearch more for the expected searches. Redundancy is not a problem, but nested objects can make your queries complicated. I think I would omit the whole resources part and do it something like this:

```
"mappings": {
    "doc": {
        "properties": {
            "location": {
                "properties": {
                    "timestamp": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "resource": {
                        "properties": {
                            "resourceName": {
                                "type": "text"
                            }
                            "resourceProbability": {
                                "type": "float"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because as I said, in this case `resource` can contain an array of objects, each having a `resourceName` and a `resourceProbability`.

Comment: Thank you for your very good answer!! This structure is the output of a software. I could create a wrapper and modify the output to choose a better format to be stored in elk. Basically my queries will look like this: "Get all the locations where there is a resource with the name equals Node1" or "Get all the locations in the last week and display a histogram where each column count the number of times that a specific resource has been located". knowing this, do you suggest to use your last proposal? I thought that create a mapping is not a must but it is a "best practice", am I wrong? thanks

Comment: Your last sentence is correct, it's not a must. However, I think the process of defining a mapping with queries in mind is very valuable. I almost always create mappings first, exceptions could be just plain logs.
To your other question: With these queries in mind, I don't think it matters too much. But I would try to avoid the nested type in this case. It seems like a sort of log to me, so you could definitely flatten it a bit. But in all honesty: try the fastest approach for you first and see if it works out :)